# Modular cascading deletion on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, modularity, cascading-deletes

I have a table (let's call it `tMainTable`) which is currently referred by many other table (and their number might just grow over time).

Several of those tables cannot just have the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause due to cycling detection.

I know I could remove the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause if I write an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on `tMainTable`.

But then whenever a new table is added as descendant of `tMainTable` one would have to edit the trigger which (as a "modularity" addict) is just lame (and risky - imagine an unexperienced user just breaks the whole thing).

So I'm seriously looking for an alternative way to proceed.

And I just have something in my mind.

What if I create a table `tMainTableID` which just hold a copy of every `ID` of `tMainTable` (copy made with `AFTER` trigger for insertion)?

Then, I create an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on `tMainTable` which first delete the corresponding row of `tMainTableID`, then delete the actual rows of `tMainTable`.

If I do that, I should have something really nice to work with: a table (`tMainTableID`) which I can "attach" AFTER DELETE triggers on to delete anything that needs to be deleted before rows of `tMainTable` get actually deleted.

```
-- Made by ME on 2014-01-27
CREATE TRIGGER tMainTableID_AFDEL_tTableChild01
AFTER DELETE
ON tMainTableID
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE T
    FROM deleted AS D
    INNER JOIN tTableChild01 AS T ON (
        T.RefToMainID = D.ID
    )
END
GO

-- Made by ME on 2015-01-01
CREATE TRIGGER tMainTableID_AFDEL_tTableChild02
AFTER DELETE
ON tMainTableID
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE T
    FROM deleted AS D
    INNER JOIN tTableChild02 AS T ON (
        T.RefToMainID = D.ID
    )
END
GO

-- Made by Iamun Kompetent on 2016-01-01
CREATE TRIGGER tMainTableID_AFDEL_tTableChild03
AFTER DELETE
ON tMainTableID
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE T
    FROM inserted AS D
    INNER JOIN tTableChild02 AS T ON (
        D.ID = D.ID
    )
END
GO
```

Do you see anything wrong with this approach or even better, do you know a better way to attain modularity?

-- EDIT: Simple example

```
create table tTest20140128 (
    id int not null primary key
)
go

create table tTest20140128_Child01 (
    id int not null primary key references tTest20140128(id) on delete no action
)
go

create table tTest20140128_Child02 (
    id int not null primary key references tTest20140128(id) on delete no action
)
go

insert tTest20140128 values (1), (2), (3)
insert tTest20140128_Child01 values (1), (2), (3)
insert tTest20140128_Child02 values (1), (2), (3)
go

delete from tTest20140128 -- Error
go

-- table for holding copies of ids
create table tTest20140128_ID (
    id int not null primary key references tTest20140128(id) on delete no action
)
go

insert tTest20140128_ID
select id from tTest20140128
go

-- trigger that keeps tTest20140128_ID up to date for new ids
create trigger tTest20140128_AFINS
on tTest20140128
after insert
as
begin
    insert tTest20140128_ID
    select id from inserted
end
go

-- Instead of delete (keeps tTest20140128_ID up to date for deleted ids)
create trigger tTest20140128_IODEL
on tTest20140128
instead of delete
as
begin
    delete ID
    from deleted AS D
    inner join tTest20140128_ID AS ID ON (
        ID.id = D.id
    )

    delete from T
    from deleted AS D
    inner join tTest20140128 AS T on (
        T.id = D.id
    )
end
go

-- Sorta "attching listeners to event" 
-- tTest20140128_Child01
create trigger tTest20140128_tTest20140128_Child01
on tTest20140128_ID
after delete
as
begin
    delete T
    from deleted as D
    inner join tTest20140128_Child01 AS T on (
        T.id = D.id
    )
end
go

-- tTest20140128_Child02
create trigger tTest20140128_tTest20140128_Child02
on tTest20140128_ID
after delete
as
begin
    delete T
    from deleted as D
    inner join tTest20140128_Child02 AS T on (
        T.id = D.id
    )
end
go

-- New tests
insert tTest20140128 values (4), (5), (6)
insert tTest20140128_Child01 values (4), (5), (6)
insert tTest20140128_Child02 values (4), (5), (6)
go

select COUNT (*) as [COUNT after insert] from tTest20140128
go

delete from tTest20140128 -- No Error
go

select COUNT (*) as [COUNT" after delete] from tTest20140128
go

drop table tTest20140128_ID
drop table tTest20140128_Child02
drop table tTest20140128_Child01
drop table tTest20140128
```

Comment: Why not just make the `INSTEAD OF` trigger on tMainTable first "delete anything that needs to be deleted before rows of tMainTable", and "then delete the actual rows of tMainTable"?

Answer (score 0):

The table creation sounds unnecessary... but your `INSTEAD OF` trigger sounds like a great idea:

How about making an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on tMainTable, that will first "delete anything that needs to be deleted before rows of tMainTable", and then "delete the actual rows of tMainTable"?